# Redirecting to previous page in CakePHP, with autoRedirect set to false

Tags: cakephp, redirect, authentication

I want to record a user's last login, so I'm doing some fairly standard things. In my UsersController:

```
if ($this->Auth->login()) {
    $this->User->id = $this->Auth->user('id');
    $this->User->saveField('last_login', date(DATE_ATOM));
    $this->Session->setFlash('Yay!'));
    $this->redirect( $this->Auth->redirectUrl() );
}
```

Also, I have set `'autoRedirect' => false` in my AppController, which is required so the data will save. The problem is, the user is not taken back to the page they were on, before they went to the login page.

What happens is, the login page thinks for some reason that the referrer was the login page, which results in the user getting kicked back to the "home page" of my app.

I'm mystified. How can I ensure that on log in, the user is taken to the page they were on prior to going to the login screen, with `'autoRedirect' => false`?

Comment: What version of Cake are you using that has both `Auth::autoRedirect` *and* `Auth::redirectUrl()`? `autoRedirect` was taken out in like 2.0 and `redirectUrl()` wasn't added until 2.3.

Comment: I'm on 2.3. I think the autoRedirect found its way in because I wasn't clear it was depreciated. In my confusion as to why redirects are acting up. The docs are kinda all over the place.

Comment: It uses the session to store the last url that it should redirect to, and falls back to `$loginRedirect` if there's nothing in the session, as stated in the docs. That's probably where the home page comes from (check your `$loginRedirect`). As for not being redirected to where they were, are you sure the session is writing correctly? `debug($this->Session->read('Auth.redirect'));` at the top of `login()` to see.

Comment: I commented out loginRedirect and I had no effect. I'll debug and see. I tested and noticed that after login, the referer was the login page, which struck me as odd.

Comment: Yeah, for some bizarre reason, on login, the session value for Auth.redirect is 'login'.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be the most reliable approach.

The link to the login page:

```
echo $this->Html->link('Login', '/login?redirect='.$this->here);
```

In the login form:

```
echo $this->Form->input('redirect', array('type' => 'hidden', 'value' => $this->request->query['redirect']));
```

In the login action in the controller

```
if (isset($this->request->data['User']['redirect'])) {
    $this->redirect( $this->request->data['User']['redirect'] );
} else {
    $this->redirect( $this->Auth->redirectUrl() );
}
```